# How can I open a malicious image in whatsapp safely?

Tags: malware, virus, whatsapp, image

I have got an image send by whatsapp on my android tabled, which I only can see when I press the download icon.

How can I see the image, without getting a virus when the image is malicious?

Are there some guides where I can run whatsapp in a sandbox or similar to download an image of an already received message? Or where can I get more info and help?

Comment: Hi @Marvhock.  I think we may want to take a step back for a second.  How do you know that the image is malicious?  If you are 100% certain that it's malicious, how do you know that there is actually an image attached?

Comment: In addition to the questions in the previous comments: if you know it is a malicious image or at least there is something unusual with it than why do you need to see it anyway? This is like asking of how to do Russian roulette without shooting yourself - simply don't do it in the first place.

Comment: Knowing that it is actually an image could help, but if its still malicious I have the same Issue. An example: You get a message you know to take serious with an file and the text "you better take action to that image", then you have two options: 1. Open the image, which is in fact just white plus a virus, your company leaks data which has large negative impact to people. Or 2. You open the file, and it is an image revealing the location of a bomb which will detonate tomorrow. How do you decide?

Comment: Is there a known vulnerability in WhatsApp which can be triggered by viewing a malicious image? I would think that this is something the developers would fix ASAP if it comes to their attention.

Comment: I think, if you see my example, when you expect the sender to have you as a special target and also he has connections to the organisations who could create customised viruses, I think chances are this custom virus could be unique, used only for some cases and don't get the developers attention. I believe some organisations have the power to always find leaks to hack you.

Comment: Is the sender known to you?  If so, it might make sense to reach out to them through another channel to confirm that they indeed sent you that message.  If not, you should probably take steps to confirm the sender's identity before you look into it.

Comment: @marvhock, your example is a bit ridiculous. If it's to the point where terrorism or nation-state actors are involved, you DO NOT try to solve it yourself. You contact the FBI or the equivalent local entity. Thing is though, anything alarmingly titled is almost definitely a phishing attempt, and should be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without asking why you know it is a malicious image and just answering your question, you could use a tool like VirtualBox and installing  a virtual machine with any operating system, for example Linux, it is free. Then you could download the linux whatsapp client from https://github.com/miccar/wazapp. When downloading and opening the image, it can only touch the virtual machine, not the host computer VirtualBox is running on. Anyway, I don't think it would do anything bad on linux, because noone really bothers to create linux viruses because not so many people use linux.